# Where should I put these fields in the MVC model?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jpanel, paintcomponent

Let's say I have three classes: `JPSModel`, `JPSView extends JPanel`, and `JPSController`. `JPSView` overrides `paintComponent()`, which draws an image at a certain `zoomFactor` at position `(renderPositionX, renderPositionY)`.

Should `zoomFactor`, `renderPositionX`, and `renderPositionY`, which the user can change, be in `JPSView` or `JPSModel`? What about methods to calculate `zoomFactor`, `renderPositionX`, and `renderPositionY` like `setZoomFit()`?

Comment: Vote 1 for model...The `zoomFactor` and `renderPositionX/Y` would depend.  If the values only have meaning to the view, then they should stay in view.  I would put `ZoomFit` in the model...

Comment: I would say that the actual position, the "physical"position should be in the model, the zoom factors should be part of the control since the model shouldn't really care how much the control/view is zooming.

Comment: I think you're suffering from a lack of context.  Before we can really answer the question, we'd need to know more. What is the model actually responsible for?  What is the view responsible for?  How would this change for different implementations?

Comment: It depends on whether your model is a data-model or a view model.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, renderPositionX and renderPositionY are just where drawImage() should render the image - not the position of the image in a document or anything. Does this change your opinion?

Comment: What about `zoom`? Is it a zoomable model?  If so, then `zoom` would belong in the model not in the view...

Comment: I would start by defining the responsibilities of the model.  What is it actually modelling?  If all it is modeling is the image, then most of the other values have no meaning to the model.  However, if the model is also modelling the zoom factor, then that value should be in the model.  It all depends on the context and requirements...

Comment: All 3 fields determine how to display the image, but since that can be thought of as the state of the application, I can't decide whether it should be in the view or model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should all be in `JPSView` since they are not related to "what" (data) is to be displayed; they all relate to "where" (positions) and "how" (at what zoom factor) the data is to be displayed.

Remember `Model` is persisted and you never save view information along with it unless it's a `ViewModel`. To give you an example, most PDF readers give you an option to reopen the PDF files at the exact same page (as well as the same zoom factor) as it was on the last time you closed it. But, that does not mean that it saves the page number and the zoom factor in the PDF itself.

To cater to such situations and if you feel like persisting "last viewed as" related view information a separate `JPSViewModel` should be created that you should ideally persist in your applications local database and not alongside the file it's processing.